# When are two C*-algebras isomorphic as Banach spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

We may consider each $C^*$-algebra as a Banach space (by forgetting the multiplication and adjoint). I wonder how drastic this step is, i.e., which properties of the $C^*$-algebra are reflected by its Banach space structure.

Clearly, finite-dimensionality and other cardinality properties can be detected. Thus, to avoid these cases, let us restrict to separable, infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras.

For commutative $C^*$-algebras the problem has been solved by Milutin. In particular, $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are isomorphic as Banach spaces for any uncountable, compact, metric spaces $X$ and $Y$.

In the paper
Hamana. **On linear topological properties of some $C^*$-algebras**, Tohoku Math. J., II. Ser. 29, 157-163 (1977).
it is shown that the Banach space structure also reflects if all irreducible representations of the $C^*$-algebra are finite-dimensional.

Let us ask what happens at the 'opposite' end of the scale:

> Question: Are all simple, separable, infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras isomorphic as Banach spaces?

Comment: Is an isomorphism of Banach spaces a bounded linear map with bounded linear inverse or an isometric isomorphism?

Comment: What are some simple and complicated examples of simple separable $C^*$-algebras?

Comment: I assume "isomorphic as Banach spaces" means linear homeomorphism. It's well known that there are non-isomorphic C*-algberas that are isometric as Banach spaces. (Google "C*-algebra not isomorphic to its opposite algebra.) The correct statement is: A and B are isomorphic as C*-algebras if and only if they are completely isometric as operator spaces.

Comment: @Bill: the "simplest" example of a simple C*-algebra (hard not to make puns here) is the algebra $K(H)$ of compact operators on a separable Hilbert space. The irrational rotation algebras $A_\theta \subset B(L^2({\bf T}))$ generated by multiplication by $e^{2\pi i t}$ and rotation by the angle $2\pi\theta$ for irrational $\theta$ are also simple. The CAR algebra is obtained by embedding $M_{2^n}$ in $M_{2^{n+1}}$ via the map $A \mapsto \left[\matrix{A&0\cr 0&A}\right]$ and completing the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty M_{2^n}$; it is also simple.

Comment: Hi Hannes, Kirchberg showed in his subalgebras of CAR algebra paper that all separable nuclear, non Type I C*-algebras are isomorphic as operator spaces (much stronger than just isomorphic as Banach spaces).  I think Christensen and others also did some things in this direction for von Neumann algebras: those results are in Pisier's operator space book, but my copy isn't with me.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thanks for clarifying. Here, two Banach spaces E and F are called isomorphic if there exists a bounded linear map from E to F that is bijective. (The inverse map will automatically be bounded, too). I do not want to assume isometric isomorphism.

Comment: @Caleb: Thanks for pointing out the result of Kirchberg. This clarifies the picture a lot. The question now seems to be whether the Banach space structure can detect nuclearity of the C*-algebra.

Comment: A complement to Caleb's remark: Being type I is invariant under a Banach space isomorphism (at least in the separable case). This follows from Haagerup--Rosenthal--Sukochev's classification of noncommutative $L^1$-spaces up to Banach isomorphism.

Comment: By Szankowski (Acta Math 1981), there is a separable (simple,  unital, etc.) $C^*$-algebra which does not have the approximation property. Such a $C^*$-algebra cannot be Banach isomorphic to a nuclear one.

Comment: Thanks, Nik.  Taka, can you give a lazy old man a hint as to why the HRS classification theorem yields that Type I is invariant under Banach space isomorphisms?

Comment: @BillJohnson: HRS proved that none of Type II and III noncommutative $L^1$ spaces Banach embed into a type I noncommutative $L^1$ space. If $A$ is a type I $C^*$-algebra, then $A^*$ is a predual of type I von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Hannes, this https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/rosenthl/pdf-papers/93.pdf survey article of Rosenthal gives a nice overview of the Banach/operator-space structure of C*-algebras.

Comment: As Taka pointed out, among the simple, separable, non-type I C*-algebras, all the nuclear ones are isomorphic as Banach spaces (even much more is true) but beyond the nuclear case this is no longer the case. This certainly answers my question, thanks.

Comment: @Tomek: Thank you for pointing out that reference, I was not aware of it. It deals exaclty with the topic I asked about.

Comment: @HannesThiel, so maybe you could organize all this long conversation into the single answer?

Comment: It is an open problem whether $C^∗_r(F_2)$ is Banach isomorphic to a nuclear $C^*$-algebra (say the CAR algebra $B$ as a model). It is known that (1) the dual of $B$ has the bounded approximation property (because it's AFD), (2) $B$ has a Schauder basis (Junge--Nielsen--Ruan--Xu, Adv. Math. 2004), and (3) $B\cong B\otimes_\alpha B$ for some reasonable tensor product (in this case the spatial tensor product). None of these properties is known for $C^∗_r(F_2)$.

Comment: This has been answered many times in the comments but is the pair $c_0$ (the null sequences) and the algebra of continuous functions on the closed unit interval not a simple counter example to your initial question?